# Error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment - How to solve this error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can anyone give me the help on this kind of error?

Actually i have the below code look like and i want to display the date in lblDate.text but got this error at the third row of the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM, yyyy"]; 
[formatter stringFromDate:myDatePickerView.date] = lblDate.text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your code should be:

```
lblDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:myDatePickerView.date];
```